# Synapse Pipeline Trigger parameters

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

We have synapse pipeline that works fine if manually triggered . But when ran in a schedule has the following error message and fails .

I verified the parameter names and the parameter does exist in the definition . Any help will be great.

**'The template language expression 'pipeline().parameters.storageaccount_name' cannot be evaluated because property 'parameters' cannot be selected."**

[image]

Comment: can you add your pipeline image for better understanding?

Comment: Hi,

Added the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Check in the JSON definition; you can modify from JSON also.
I've had some problems, and solved them by going to the JSON directly and modifying it there, or finding differences that were not synchronized.

Top right `{}` icon.

Comment: Can you clarify what they should be looking for in the JSON?

Answer (score 0):

This was a blunder in my workflow . According to the documentation that trigger can pass parameters to pipeline and not the otherway around . In my trigger definition json I was referring to pipeline parameters ( somewhat similar to referencing an undeclared variable in programming context ). Hence it  broke . After removing the references to the pipeline parameters the triggers worked .

If you want to pass parameters to a pipeline from the trigger then define them in the trigger and the pipeline can reference them with a notation **@trigger().parametername** .

Hope this helps someone.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-use-trigger-parameterization

[image]